# Upgrade stalled. 14.04 to 15

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, xorg, 15.10

Whilst upgrading from 14.04 to 15 the installation black screened. I waited for 15 minutes then rebooted. Ubuntu 15 started in terminal mode. How do I verify the installation and start the desktop?

---

Further information as requested.
- result of `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

My system is a HP Pavilion dual booted with Windows 10.

Memory 7.0 GiB
Processor AMD A8-4555M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 4 
Graphics Gallium 0.4 on AMD ARUBA (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.6.2)
OS type 64-bit
Disk Partitioning 46 GiB Root, 279 GiB /home, 15 GiB swap. The rest is Windows or unallocated.

The upgrade was direct from 14.04 to 15.10 via the software updater.

The good news is that `startx` worked. When I then shutdown and restarted I'm back to business as usual.

Comment: hello, we need some more info here. Please edit this post and provide system info as well as specs, if you think it's a bug please post it on Launchpad to allow dev's to track your bug request

Comment: In Terminal mode type:   _sudo startx_  (enter password if necessary). This command should start the desktop, if the upgrade went well.

Comment: @ipselute I believe `startx` is designed to be run without `sudo`

Comment: @Dave T: is the problem solved or still open?

Comment: Yes. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

## Regarding what to expect

An upgrade from 14.04 should normally either go to 16.04 or 15.04 - but not 15.10.

## Check Version

You can check your Ubuntu version via:

```
lsb_release -a
```

## Start UI

You could start the x server by

```
startx
```

It might as well work to just start the login manager service

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

Comment: +1 This option should work. but don't mark it as accepted yet. **We need some more info**